# Click Event in Jquery is not firing

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list tag in HTML like this ...

```
<li><a id="teams" class="first" href="#"</a></li>
```

Now as per my requirement ,I want to fire a click event on this anchor link.Here is the code that i am trying but click event is not getting fired..

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

            $("teams").click(function(event) {
                  alert("hello");
            });     

        });
```

Here is the Demo Fiddle..
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qax4t/)

Please tell me where i am wrong ..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector that you meant as `id selector` was wrong. Please see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to know more about jquery selectors.

Try,

```
  $("#teams").click(function(event) {
     alert("hello");
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qax4t/1/)

Answer (score 2):

While accessing `id`s use `#`. And while accessing `class` use `.`.

Here's your udpated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qax4t/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector. You Should be using id selector `#`:

```
$("#teams").click(function(event) {
              alert("hello");
        });
```

or for using class selector:

```
$("a.first").click(function(event) {
              alert("hello");
        });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qax4t/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an [`id selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you must precede the selector with `#`:

> Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

Code:

```
$("#teams").click(function(event) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8xJRe/

Side note, your `<a>` element markup is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

For access the id use '#'like this:

```
                 ('#team').click(function(){
                     //code here
                 })
```

For access the class use '.' like this

```
                  ('.team').click(function(){
                     //code here
                 })
```